# socket code only works on a 16 byte buffer

Tags: c, sockets

I am having difficulty changing the amount of data my server sends and getting it to send data. This code fails, but works when I change the size of `buffer` to 16 characters.

This is the code from transferclient.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 218

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned short portno = 10823;

    int sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char buffer[32] = {0};
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    printf("Attemping to connect\n");
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Connected\n");
    read(sock, buffer, 16);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code from transferserver.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 218

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int portno = 10823;          /* port to listen on */

    int server_fd, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt =1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Attaching the socket to the port
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(portno);
   
   
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Listening\n");
    
    while ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, (socklen_t*) &addrlen)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", new_socket);
        printf("Socket connected\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Server side**

Listening

4

Socket connected

````
***Client Side***
``` 
Attemping to connect

Connected
````

When I change the line in transferclient.c to 32 bytes.

```
char buffer[32] = {0};
```

The sockets fail to connect.

***Server side***

```
Listening
```

***Client Side***

```
Attemping to connect
```

Why is that?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is somewhere in the code that you are not showing us. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: According to the output that you posted in your question, neither `"Connected"` nor `"\nConnection Failed \n"` gets printed. Are you sure that is correct? If so, does your program crash?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It seems like the socket starts to connect and gets hung.

Comment: I suggest that you change `printf("Connected");` to `printf("Connected\n");` (add newline character). Or you should add an `fflush( stdout );` after that statement. If you don't make sure that the message gets flushed from the output buffer, then you may never see it, for example if the program enters an infinite loop afterwards. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/12149471) for more information. An alternative would be to use `stderr` instead of `stdout` for the diagnostic messages, because that stream is normally unbuffered.

Comment: Neither of those helped. The output is still the same as before.

Comment: If you can't provide a [mre], then please at least show us all the code between printing `"Attemping to connect"` and `"Connected"`. Currently you are not showing us the `printf` statement which prints `"Attemping to connect"`.

Comment: If changing the size of an array causes the behavior of the program to change significantly, then this could be a symptom of the stack getting corrupted. If you are using gcc or clang compiler, then you may want to compile your code with [`fsanitize=address`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), so that the compiler will add some additional runtime tests, to see if this is happening.

Comment: I included where the print statement is for attempting to connect and I already have that compiler option added as well.

Comment: If you need debugging help, a [mcve] is mandatory.

Comment: Could you post the code for declaring and initializing serv_code.

Comment: How long did you wait for `connect` to return? If the server is not reacting to the connection request, then it may take about a minute (maybe longer, depending on your operating system) for `connect` to timeout and report failure. However, this behavior should have nothing to do whether the array size is 16 or 32.

Comment: I have included the minimal viable code.

Answer (score 1):

In the client code, you don't seem to be setting all fields of `serv_addr`.

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

[...]

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
```

Because you are not setting `serv_addr.sin_addr`, it will have an indeterminate (garbage) value when you pass it to the function `connect`.

My guess is that changing the size of the array caused the `sin_addr` field of `serv_addr` to have a different initial (garbage) value. That is why the code works when `buffer` has a size of `16` but fails when it has a size of `32`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion... apart of what has already been mentioned in other answers, you are lacking constants... you should define something like:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE    (32)
```

and then use

```
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

and

```
    read(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

or, if you don't like this approach, use this other:

```
    char buffer[32];
```

and later

```
    read(sock, buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

but if you put different numbers in the buffer size and in the `read()` call it is normal that it doesn't work ok when you call `read()` with `16` as the number of characters to read.

By the way, it is common that you ask a socket to read a fixed amount of bytes, and it returns less bytes than the amount you requested, so **IT IS VERY IMPORTANT THAT YOU CHECK THE RETURN VALUE OF `read(2)`**.  Something like:

```
    ssize_t n = read(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

as from `buffer[n]` to `buffer[sizeof buffer - 1]` there can be nothing useful to your code (rests of a previous read, or similar)  It is quite common to print it with something like:

```
    if (n > 0)
        printf("Read: [%.*s]\n", n, buffer);
```

that will print that number of received valid characters, and not what is behind them in the buffer.